# Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses, cannot put byte in resb buffer

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64, mach-o

First I'm on OS X(x86-64 set) and I use nasm.
I'm following a tutorial to asm, and I'm writing a function to reverse a string.
My problem is that I can't put byte in my resb buffer.
I have `Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses` error. I did some research, tried a lot of things(like lea, or mov into a register first) nothing seems to solve my problem.

Below is my code and my problem is on: `mov [output + rdi], eax`(I'm trying to write the reverse string of input db buffer to output resb 12 buffer) in `reverseStr` label

```
section .data
    nl db 0xa
    input db "Hello world!"

section .bss
    output resb 12

section .text
    global start
    global _main

start:
    jmp _main
    ret

_main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rsi, input
    xor rcx, rcx
    cld
    mov rdi, $ + 15
    call calculateStrLength
    xor rax, rax
    xor rdi, rdi
    jmp reverseStr

calculateStrLength:
    cmp byte [rsi], 0
    je exit
    lodsb
    push rax
    inc rcx
    jmp calculateStrLength

reverseStr:
    cmp rcx, 0
    ;je printResult
    pop rax
    mov [output + rdi], eax
    dec rcx
    inc rdi
    jmp reverseStr
```

Comment: You can always get the 64-bit address of `output` and put it in a register (like _RDX_) and then do the memory access with _RDX_. You can do `lea rdx, [rel output]` (the `rel` forces it to use RIP-relative addressing) to load and then do the MOV this way `mov [rdx + rdi], eax` . Since `output` never changes you can do the `lea` and load _RDX_ once outside the loop.

Comment: Yes you are right, it worked well. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably use `default rel` at the top of your file.  It's unfortunately not enabled by default in NASM/YASM.